# Why do “sparks” fly off of hot metal when compressed?

Tags: material-science, metals

[image]

Link to video: https://www.instagram.com/p/B3T2iDQJePw/

Why, when this hot metal is crushed from the top down, do all these “sparks”, or whatever this may be, fly off?

Please can someone explain what the physics is behind why this happens and what it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hot iron oxide, or rust forms when the metal comes in contact with air (oxygen).

When pressed, the very hot rust flies off. Subsequent compression then pushes carbon atoms from the metal surface into the air, that combine with oxygen forming carbon dioxide, which causes the sparking.

The reason for this sparking is identical to what happens when you apply a grinding disc to a metals surface. Hot carbon flies off the metal surface that combines with oxygen, causing sparks.

Answer (score 2):

That red-hot billet of steel is coated with a layer of iron oxide which forms the instant that the billet comes into contact with air. The first time the billet is crushed, you can see the oxide coating flake off, exposing fresh iron to the oxygen in the air- and then the bare metal burns until a new oxide layer is formed. Then the fire goes out.

The next time the billet is crushed, the oxide is thin and it cracks instead of flaking off in big pieces. In each crack, fresh metal comes into contact with oxygen and a flame jets out of the crack for a moment.